# Django and React - npm run watch/build very slow

Tags: reactjs, django, npm, npm-build

I'm trying to make a django/drf and react project but it takes 15+ seconds for npm run build to finish. What are my options here? It's not feasible to wait that long after every change I make to the front end. Should I keep the react and django parts separate till the end?

I followed these instructions since I'm new to npm:

https://medium.com/how-to-react/use-npm-watch-to-auto-build-your-reactjs-app-6ed0e5d6cb00

Comment: What did you use to create your react project ? create-react-app, vitejs, plain webpack config ?

Comment: create-react-app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need a development setup with React & Django, you can :

- do `npm run start` to open your create-react-app project in development
- add `"proxy": "localhost:8000"` in your `package.json` so that AJAX requests from React are forwarded to Django
- make sure Django is running on port 8000 with `./manage.py runserver`

The `npm run build` is only needed to deploy usually.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, being able to do API calls should be sufficient for what I need during development.